# Weblogic JAX-WS authorisation

Tags: java, web-services, security, jax-ws, weblogic12c

I'm deploying a JAX-WS web service on **Weblogic 12c (12.1.3)** using the administration console.

During the deployment, on the "*Optional Settings*" tab, under the "*Security*" section, I make sure that I select the "*Advanced: Use a custom model that you have configured on the realm's configuration page.*" option. After the deployment, I click on the link of the web service under the application and using the "*Configuration -> WS-Policy*" tab, I associate the port with the Weblogic policy "*policy:Wssp1.2-2007-Https-UsernameToken-Plain.xml*".

To restrict access to the web service, I go to the *"Security -> Policies"* tab and configure the role that the user must have in order to access the web service.

The problem I'm facing is that, the security settings seem to be completely ignored by Weblogic. The behaviour I'm observing currently is that any SOAP request that sends a UsernameToken with a valid username and password, is able to access the service. This is true even if I change the security settings to be "**Deny access to everyone**"!

Another problem is that when I call *WebServiceContext.isUserInRole("someRole")*, it always returns **false**, even if the user has the role in question.

Note that Weblogic is configured to authenticate users against Oracle Identity Manager and the roles are configured there as well.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?